# Gem Install Error

Tags: linux, rubygems

When trying to run gem install rake bundler I get the following error

```
rvmsudo gem install rake bundler
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

What might be causing this problem and how do I fix it?

OS: Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit

Comment: This has since been answered elsewhere on SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your missing the zlib package.

try:

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

then uninstall and reinstall your gem version with rvm

Comment: Tried, while it needed installed, I still get the same error.

Comment: If the command doesn't work try: `rvm pkg install zlib --verify-downloads 1`