# cannot load such file -- zlib even after using rvm pkg install zlib

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, rvm

I installed zlib package and ruby 1.9.3 using rvm, but whenever I try to install
gems it says
`cannot load such file -- zlib`

The commands I used to install are

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

```
$ rvm pkg install zlib

$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=/home/username/.rvm/usr \
    --with-iconv-dir=/home/username/.rvm/usr \
    --with-zlib-dir=/home/username/.rvm/usr \
    --with-openssl-dir=/home/username/.rvm/usr

$ rvm use 1.9.3

$ gem install heroku
ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

All the help on this subject tells me to just do `rvm pkg install zlib`, and
then reinstall the ruby with `--with-zlib-dir=/home/username/.rvm/usr`, but this
didn't work.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I ended up installing zlib from apt-get and then reinstalling ruby to *not* use the rvm directory for zlib.

Here's how do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

**[Edit]** As commenter @chrisfinne mentions, on CentOS/RedHat based systems:

```
$ sudo yum install zlib-devel
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: or sudo yum install zlib-devel

Comment: Well, regardless of the OS, @chrisfinne 's advice is still useful (for me at least)!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Although I had to recompile once more since I was missing libssl-dev too (I needed it because rvm wanted to fetch  the ruby sources via HTTPS) :-)

Comment: How to do this with rbenv?

Answer (score 9):

The both other responses were almost right...

The [rvm site for zlib](https://rvm.io/packages/zlib/) provides a quick fix!

On the top off the page is a "Quick fix" follow it's instructions, it will:

- fix your installation,
- provide you instructions what to do to install zlib from your system
- and show how to reinstall ruby

Answer (score 2):

Use autolibs to install dependencies:

```
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

RVM will automatically install missing dependencies and use them for compiling ruby.

More details on autolibs => http://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is described in rvm github repo, [issue #3389](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3389).

Run

```
rvm install 2.3.0 --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8
```

for ruby **2.3.0** version.

Answer (score 1):

```
rvm pkg install openssl && rvm pkg install zlib && rvm pkg install libyaml &&
  rvm pkg install iconv
rvm install 1.9.3-p0 --with-opt-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr \
  --with-libxml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8 \
  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a bunch of package dependencies like the one on zlib-devel. They're nasty because there's nothing to indicate you need the library until get some obscure error message while trying to do something routine.

The solution is to use [rvm](https://rvm.io/). Use it even if you only need one version of ruby. Why? Because then you can do

```
rvm requirements
```

This will probe your particular OS and produce a set of commands you can copy back to the command line to install those missing packages.