# Issue in install rvm on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

Rvm One line installer is giving me issues ie:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Iam getting this error:

```
 ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
   cannot load such file -- zlib
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
   uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

Comment: This thread must be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One library is missing. Try executing this first:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

EDIT:

In the rvm webpage there's a section about this issue https://rvm.io/packages/zlib/

EDIT(mpapis):

The installer command was showing short screen with instruction to install this library, next time read it before pressing `q`.