# Install bundler with rbenv/ruby-build

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I've installed rbenv and downloaded a ruby using ruby-build, e.g.

```
rbenv global 1.9.3-p448
gem env # This show my customized ruby gem paths instead the system one, 
        # so it works!
```

Then I install bundler,

```
# gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler

ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)

    cannot load such file -- zlib

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)

    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

If I don't use rbenv and use my system ruby, I can install bundler. but how to install when I am using rbenv?

Comment: What is the output of `which ruby` and `which gem` when rbenv ruby selected? Did you do `rbenv rehash` after installing ruby with ruby-build?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe related to this [similar question with RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib)

Try installing zlib first :

APT :

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

YUM :

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel
```

Then reinstall ruby

Answer (score 0):

I had  a same problem when I was using lodash-rails with Rails,

This is an usual problem when you have standalone ruby  along with  `rbenv` OR RVM OR any version managers , Its always good and stable to remove all ruby installations in your system and use only rbenv OR RVM as your ruby platform .

People use rbenv or RVM so that they can switch between any ruby version as per the requirement  .

**Possible reason for your problem : -**

I think bundler is trying to install some dependency and that particular dependency is referring to system env path which set in your

```
.bashrc     OR 
.bash_profile     OR 
.profile file
```

normally bundler checks for gem path which might have been set in any of your bash profile files  .

set that gem path to your .rbenv/version/versionnumber/gems folder .

in your home directory . Check in the above listed files and see if you have any ruby references , if so remove just remove them .

Answer (score 0):

I have a bash script that makes ruby/rails install easy on debian/ubuntu. It also installs many dependencies that you might need.

You can find it here: https://github.com/yoones/railsondeb

If you encounter any problem, don't hesitate to let me know (an issue will do).