# Gem install error related to missing library

Tags: ruby, centos, rubygems

I installed Ruby v2.1.4 from source. I  installed all necessary libaries using:

```
yum install gcc g++ make automake autoconf curl-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel httpd-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel sqlite-devel
```

All succeeded.

Now when I want to install a gem with:

```
gem install bundler-1.7.4.gem
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I am sure that zlib is installed:

```
locate zlib
```

results in a long list of

```
/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/kernel/crypto/zlib.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/kernel/lib/zlib_deflate
/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/kernel/lib/zlib_deflate/zlib_deflate.ko
/lib64/rsyslog/lmzlibw.so
/usr/include/zlib.h
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/zlib_codec.py
/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/zlib_codec.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/zlib_codec.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlibmodule.so
/usr/local/share/doc/ruby/capi/html/db/d74/zlib_8c.html
/usr/local/share/doc/ruby/capi/html/db/d74/zlib_8c_source.html
/usr/local/share/ri/2.1.0/system/Zlib/zlib_version-c.ri
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/ChangeLog
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/FAQ
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/README
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/README
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/algorithm.txt
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/example.c
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/minigzip.c
/usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/include/config/zlib
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/include/config/crypto/zlib.h
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/include/config/jffs2/zlib.h
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/include/config/ubifs/fs/zlib.h
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/include/config/zlib/deflate.h
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/include/config/zlib/inflate.h
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/include/linux/zlib.h
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/lib/zlib_deflate
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/lib/zlib_inflate
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/lib/zlib_deflate/Makefile
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/lib/zlib_inflate/Makefile
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- zlib even after using rvm pkg install zlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib), specifically this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib#comment-15076165

Comment: @PatrickOscity as long as it actually could be duplicate its another case because I am unable to use Internet Connection at my CentOS so each try of using rvm will fale. however I did manage to make it otherway by following steps in http://visibletrap.blogspot.com/2013/10/installing-ruby-cannot-load-such-file.html

Comment: Nice. Please add that as an answer and accept your own answer as soon as it is possible. This will maybe help future visitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution [at this blog](http://visibletrap.blogspot.com/2013/10/installing-ruby-cannot-load-such-file.html). I am unable to use `rvm` because server have no internet connection even through proxy.

While installing ruby from sources doing the following solved the issue:

- Remove the installed Ruby with `make clean`
- Install libssl-dev with your OS's package manager of choice. E.g. `apt-get install libssl-dev`
- Install zlib1g-dev with your OS's package manager of choice. E.g. `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`
- Config make file to include openssl by go to `ext/openssl` and run `ruby extconf.rb`
- Config make file to include zlib by go to `ext/zlib` and run `ruby extconf.rb`
- Go back to ruby source code directory run `make && make install`
- You should be able to successfully run `gem install bundler`