# Why does 'gem update --system' give me an error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm going through a server setup guide and I'm trying to download rubygems:

```
gem update --system
```

I am on version 2.2.2 of ruby gems, version 2.1.2p95 of ruby, and ubuntu 14.04, but it doesn't appear to be working. Looking further into this, I found an alternative to the command 
[here](https://rubygems.org/pages/download) on their official site.

However, when I run:

```
~/ruby-src/ruby-2.1.2$ sudo gem install rubygems-update
```

I'm still getting the same error which is:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: As for me, use bundler and you will not have any of this problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- zlib even after using rvm pkg install zlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib)