# Installing Rails with compiled version of Ruby (Debian)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, debian

I have a Debian 8 Jessie server and I've compiled Ruby sources (https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source).

When I check the version of ruby with `ruby -v`, I have a correct output 
`ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]`

However, when I run the following command: 
    `gem install rails`, I have the following error message:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: Based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib i think you should download zlib1g and then rebuild ruby

Comment: Hello, i've installed zlib1g-dev as you guys suggested and recompiled ruby sources - but i've still got the same problem. Ruby is installed in the following directory `/usr/bin/ruby`